# does lombok have side effects on jpa

Tags: java, jpa, lombok

I am working on converting a jpa entity to use lombok. The resulting code is the following:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TEST")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
class Test {
   ...
   @Column(name = "FORMATTING")
   @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
   private FormatType formatType;
   ...
}
```

The resulting error message contains the following

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing column: formatType in TEST
```

I am really not sure what to google here. (I  tried pasting everything before `formatType` into google - didn't see anything)

## NOTE:

1. fields have been renamed and aspects which do not appear relevant have been omitted, for the sake of brevity and privacy. if something looks like a typo, it probably is. please let me know if you notice something so that i can address it.
2. the 3 lines describing the field are unchanged from the code i'm working with

## EDIT:

I just noticed this right before the error message

```
13:22:19,967 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 57) HHH000261: Table found: TABLE
13:22:19,967 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 57) HHH000037: Columns: [..., formatType, ...]
13:22:19,968 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 57) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."...": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."...": javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: ...] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
```

## Should be functional

```
  @Entity
  @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
  @Table(name = "PARENT")

  public abstract class Parent implements Serializable {

     private static final long serialVersionUID = 1;
     @Id
     @Column(name = "ID")
     @GeneratedValue
     private long id;
     @Column(name = "ENABLED")
     private boolean enabled;
  }

  @Entity
  @Table(name = "CHILD")
  @Data
  @NoArgsConstructor
  @AllArgsConstructor
  public class Child extends Parent {
     /** XXX: HERE BE DRAGONS */
     @Column(name = "ENUM_1")
     @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
     private Enum1 enum1;
     @Column(name = "ENUM_2")
     @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
     private Enum2 enum2;
     /** XXX: NO MORE DRAGONS */
     @Column(name = "FREQUENCY")
     private String frequency;
     @Column(name = "EMPTY")
     private boolean empty;
     @Column(name = "MAX_SIZE")
     private int maxSize;
  }
  public enum Enum1 {
     A,
     B,
     C
  }
  public enum Enum2 {
     X,
     Y,
     Z
  }
```

I have rolled back the lombok changes, I would still like to know what the issue is, but there is no rush. Also, thanks to this lovely little bug i am about 4 hours behind so i may be a little slow on the responses.

The pk of the child table is an fk to the parent table, and without lombok everything appears to work, despite the fact that the `Child` class has no id.

**SOLUTION:**

I completely forgot about asking this. Not long ago I revizited this problem. To explain the solution lets look at a slightly simplified version of the first example i included.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TEST")
@Setter
@Getter
class Test {
   ...
   @Column(name = "FORMATTING")
   @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
   private FormatType formatType;
   ...
}
```

It would appear that Lombok will give you this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TEST")
class Test {
   ...
   @Column(name = "FORMATTING")
   @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
   private FormatType formatType;

   public FormatType getFormatType() {
      return formatType;
   }
   public void setFormatType(FormatType formatType) {
      this.formatType = formatType;
   }
   ...
}
```

Note that the annotations are still attached to the *field*. Now, I am not certain if it is just the version or implementation of JPA that we are using but I gather that if an accessor is defined jpa just ignores any annotations besides `@Column` (as well as any parameters specified for `@Column` - which is why jpa was looking for the wrong column name). So we actually need:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TEST")
class Test {
   ...
   private FormatType formatType;

   @Column(name = "FORMATTING")
   @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
   public FormatType getFormatType() {
      return formatType;
   }
   public void setFormatType(FormatType formatType) {
      this.formatType = formatType;
   }
   ...
}
```

After a great deal of confusion trying to find examples and fill in some specifics regarding how lombok does its thing (to be fair I am very easily confused) i discovered this little gem: [`onMethod=@__({@AnnotationsHere})`](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/onX). Utilizing this feature I came up with the following:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TEST")
@Setter
class Test {
   ...
   @Getter(onMethod=@__({
         @Column(name = "FORMATTING"),
         @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
      }))
   private FormatType formatType;

   ...
}
```

And presto it works. Now that we have what is apparently the only available solution I would like to address the question we are all pondering at the moment: is that really any cleaner than just writing the method manually and attaching the annotations there? Answer: ... I have no idea. I am just happy I found a solution.

Comment: When specifically do you get the error message?

Comment: when hibernate is processing persistence info

Comment: Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem. Posting what the actual generated Java code is would be helpgul, too: use a decompiler to decompile the generated class and see what it looks like.

Comment: i'll work on that but in the meantime, i take it this means that lombok shouldn't have jpa related side-effects?

Comment: AFAIK, lombok is just a compile-time thing.

Comment: I am now pretty sure that this is related to the combination of `@Enumerated` and `@Column`. the other fields are actually looking for the name specified by the annotation. it is just breaking on the enumerations. Also, it actually looks like this code is nightmarishly complicated with inheritance and whatnot. I don't think i will be able to put together a running example in a reasonable amount of time. if that's a deal-breaker i understand, and thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: *Also, it actually looks like this code is nightmarishly complicated with inheritance and whatnot*: your example doesn't have inheritance at all. It's missing an ID. We have no idea where the ID is defined and annotated. That's why posting a complete minimal example reproducing the problem is important. My guess is that you annotated the getId() method, making all the field annotations irrelevant, because hibernate looks for annotations on getters. A complete minimal example would allow confirming that.

Comment: yea i had abbreviated it alot, there was an id. Okay, i'll see if i can get something whipped up

Comment: thanks for the patience folks. got called away. how is that?

Answer (score 3):

Its strange. Can you show more code?
I'm trying to write a simple project with part of code like in your question and it worked. I used Spring Boot and MySQL. Try to check your configuration. There is my code:

**Enum:**

```
public enum FormatType {

    FIRST_TYPE, SECOND_TYPE
}
```

**Table in MySQL:**

```
create table TEST
(
    ID int auto_increment primary key,
    FORMATTING int not null
);
```

**Entity:**

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "TEST")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Test {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "FORMATTING")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    private FormatType formatType;
}
```

**Repository:**

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface TestRepository extends JpaRepository<Test, Integer> {
}
```

**Service:**

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class TestService {

    private TestRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    public TestService(TestRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public List<Test> getAllTestEntities() {
        return repository.findAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: having a little trouble coming up with sanitized sql to go along with the new example.

Comment: but yea that is pretty much what my example was going for. thanks for going the extra mile

Answer (score 2):

Is unlikely that lombok causes runtime problems, as it works on precompile time, you might find useful to decompile the generated code, I sometimes find that the order in which lombok annotations are placed in the source code affect the final result, so, you use @Data and @NoArgsConstructor , I guess you can remove @NoArgsConstructor an try to see if that solves your problem.

Comment: it's a compile time problem

Comment: yes, this worked for me too - removed NoArgsConstructor and RequiredArgsConstructor - i was plagued by duplicate NotNull constraint definitions errors at runtime

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem with Lombok and JPA but I setup the Lombok and it worked as expected. Below is the code:

**Controller**

```
package com.sms.controller;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.sms.model.StudentModel;
import com.sms.persistance.StudentRepository;

@RestController
public class StudentController {

    @Autowired
    private StudentRepository sr;

    @PostMapping("/addstudent")
    public String addStudent(@Valid @RequestBody StudentModel studentModel) {
        StudentModel result = sr.save(studentModel);
        return result.equals(null)?"Failed":"Successfully Saved student data";
    }

}
```

**Model**

```
package com.sms.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;

@Data
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name="student", schema="development")
public class StudentModel {

    @Id
    @Column(name="student_id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name="student_name")
    private String studentname;
    @Column(name="student_address")
    private String studentaddress;



}
```

**Repository**

```
package com.sms.persistance;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.sms.model.StudentModel;

@Repository
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<StudentModel, Integer>{

}
```

Comment: I've put `@Data` at the first before any others JPA annotations, somehow it works, but I'm not sure yet is it about annotation order in the Entity class or its kind of intermittent things when using `lombok` and `JPA` together